# Добавление и отображение постов Laravel и Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

подскажите как правильно написать ajax скрипт для ларки.

У меня есть роут

```
Route::post('/{id}/store', 'ProfileController@store')->name('profile.store');
```

И метод который его обрабатывает

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = new Profile();
    $post->message = $request->message;
    $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($request->file('img')) {
        $path = Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('img'));
        $url = Storage::url($path);
        $post->img = $url;
    }

    $post->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

В базе такие поля

```
id
user_id
message
img(null)
created_at(null)
updated_at(null)
```

Форма добавления поста

```
<div class="card-header">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form action="{{route('profile.store', ['id' => Auth::user()->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" cols="100" rows="4" placeholder="О чем думаешь?"></textarea>
                                <input type="file" id="img" name="img" value="Прикрепить изображение" class="mt-2">
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mt-4">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

И вывод постов

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="list-group-item py-5 textpost" id="textpost">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="img-post" style="background-image: url({{$user->avatar ?? asset('img/default-ava.jpg')}});"></div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="media-heading"><small class="float-right text-muted">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
                                <h5>{{$user->name}}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="{{$post->img ?? ''}}" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="text-muted text-small">{!!$post->message!!}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if(Auth::check())
                        @if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id)
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <form action="{{route('deletePost', ['id' => $post->id])}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf @method('DELETE')
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-2" value="Удалить пост">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

В аяксе я особо не силён, поэтому попробовал применить скрипт от другого проекта, написанного на чистом php, вообщем что у меня вышло и естественно не работает

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){

            var message = $("#message").val();
            var img = $("#img").val();

            $("#message").val('');
            $("#img").val('');

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route(\'profile.store\', [\'id\' => Auth::user()->id])}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {message:message, img:img},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#loader").show();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#textpost").html($(data).find("#textpost").html());
                    $("#loader").hide();
                },
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. вам следует добавить токен:

```html
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

2. также в методе контроллера первым аргументом написать $id
3. и возвращайте из контроллера не редирект а хотя бы массив.
4. также стоит познакомиться с валидаторами и обернуть код контроллера в try-catch и в каллбеке js-функции обрабатывать возможные ошибки.
5. Рекомендую почитать документацию. Всю. [Ларавел](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-introduction)
   Удачи вам.